# Find minimum depth of a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I need to find the minimum depth of a binary tree. My code fails on this test case: `[-9, -3, 2, null, 4, 4, 0, -6, null, -5]`.

> Given a binary tree, find its minimum depth Example:
>
> Given binary tree `[3, 9, 20, null, null, 15, 7]`,
>
> ```
>     3
>    / \
>   9  20
>     /  \
>    15   7
> ```
>
> return its minimum depth = 2.

```java
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {

    public int count(TreeNode root) { 
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1 + Math.max(count(root.left), count(root.right));
    }

    public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
        int left = 0, right = 0;

        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (root.right == null) {
           return  1 + count(root.left);
        }      

        if (root.left == null) {
            return  1 + count(root.right);
        }

        left = count(root.left);
        right = count(root.right);

        return  1 + Math.min(left, right);
    }
}
```

- output = 4
- expected = 3

Comment: For which input `TreeNode` do expect this output?

Comment: @Lutz Horn I believe the expected output/input he wrote of 4 and 3 are referring to the binary tree in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in using Math.max instead of Math.min

```
public int minDepth(TreeNode root)
{

    if(root == null)
        return 0;

    return 1 + Math.min(minDepth(root.left), minDepth(root.right));
}
```

Comment: It's not quite so simple as switching max to min. This only works on trees where every node has 2 children, otherwise it gives a false positive for a missing child node. Consider the tree `[a, b]` where `b` is `a`'s left child. The depth should be 2 but this gives 1.

Answer (score 0):

The helper function seems like overkill here; it's easier to put all of the logic into one function and pass counts up the stack.

There are 3 cases:

- If this node is null, return 0.
- If there are no children, this node is a leaf. Return 1.
- If there is a left and/or right child, this node is an interior node. Recursively compute the minimum depths for any present children and add 1 to count the current node. If either left or right child is missing, we'll ignore it in the computation by coalescing its minimum value to infinity.

Here's the code:

```
public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        return 1;
    }

    int left = root.left == null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : minDepth(root.left);
    int right = root.right == null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : minDepth(root.right);
    return Math.min(left, right) + 1;
}
```